# Listing Bluetooth Devices Natively In Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, bluetooth

I'm trying to write a *very* simple terminal app that will scan for Bluetooth devices at regular intervals and display the Bluetooth network address (the hex digits) of every Bluetooth device within range. My target platform is Mac OS X, so I assume that this will involve Objective-C. I don't have any experience in Objective-C (though I have all the basics of C), but this seems like it should be pretty straightforward.

Where can I find documentation and example code (or a tutorial, or code that some answerer has used in the past) for listing Bluetooth devices quickly and natively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following Mac Dev Center reference maybe of interest to you. It is a little in depth but does have code examples.

[Introduction to Bluetooth Device Access Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/Bluetooth/BT_Intro/BT_Intro.html)

Comment: I couldn't find any code for device discovery - I'm a little tired so I'll have a better look later. Thanks!

Comment: You know what, you are correct. It mentions the BluetoothUI framework for device discovery, but no examples on how to use it. I will continue looking and edit this post with what I find, since I am now interested in how to do this. It is too early for research. :)

Comment: Did you manage to find anything? I'm still hunting around for a solution with no luck!

Answer (score 6):

Using bluetooth with Objective-C can be achieved with the IOBluetooth framework.

An example of some useful classes for basic operation are:

- `IOBluetoothDevice`

  - connection methods
  - `[IOBluetoothDevice pairedDevices]` returns an NSArray of paired devices
  - alot of other stuff
- `IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry`

  - looks for available devices
- `IOBluetoothHostController`

  - the `powerState` property can tell you if your own bluetooth is on or off

---

Here is some example code for using `IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry` to get the address of each bluetooth device in range. Start the inquiry process with something like:

```
IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry *inquirer = [IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry inquiryWithDelegate:self];
// Configure further here if necessary
[inquirer start];
```

Now, you can get the address of the found devices using the `IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryDelegate` methods:

```
#pragma mark - IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryDelegate Methods

- (void) deviceInquiryComplete:(IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry *)sender error:(IOReturn)error aborted:(BOOL)aborted {
    NSArray *devices = [sender foundDevices];
    for (IOBluetoothDevice *device in devices) {
        const BluetoothDeviceAddress *address = [device getAddress];
        // Do something with address
    }
    [sender performSelector:@selector(start) withObject:nil afterDelay:7];
}
```

Comment: Could this possibly be rewritten in Swift? Thanks!

Comment: Or more specifically, I'm very uneducated with Obj-C but do understand Bridging Headers. Do both of these go in the header file, or where are these located? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A command line app usually doesn't use the RunLoop but `IOBluetoothDeviceInquire` relies on the RunLoop of the main thread.  This requirement is not documented, and it can lead to all kinds of environment-dependent behavior, but mostly it leads to unsuccessful searches.  In particular, setting up your own thread and driving its RunLoop is not sufficient.

I found out about this by trial and error.  But for the benefit of mankind the result, a complete example of a simple command line application that searches for Bluetooth devices, can be found [in this github project](https://github.com/Agamnentzar/bluetooth-serial-port/blob/f50db3d28d256ea5ec03e55c223e8cf421cf15da/src/osx/btScan.mm) .

The relevant parts are the delegate handler

```
// The purpose of this delegate is to finish the RunLoop once the inquiry completes.

@interface DiscoveryFinisher : NSObject<IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryDelegate>
- (void) deviceInquiryComplete: (IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry *)sender error: (IOReturn)error aborted: (BOOL)aborted;
@end

@implementation DiscoveryFinisher
- (void)deviceInquiryComplete: (IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry *)sender error: (IOReturn)error aborted: (BOOL)aborted
{
    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}
@end
```

and the code which does the search (`CFRunLoopRun` blocks until the search is finished):

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        DiscoveryFinisher* df = [[DiscoveryFinisher alloc] init];
        IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry* bdi = [[IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry alloc] initWithDelegate: df];
        [bdi setUpdateNewDeviceNames:NO];
        if ([bdi start] != kIOReturnSuccess) {
            return -1;
        }

        CFRunLoopRun();
        [bdi stop];

        NSArray *foundDevices = [bdi foundDevices];
        //... do something with them
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here the delegate is used only to stop the RunLoop in the end, but you can implement other parts of the protocol to, e.g. continuously update the list of devices.  A word of warning since this is most useful in a multithreaded application: if you do so, you have to stay aware of the mainThread in order to correctly drive the RunLoops.  In general, the safest approach is to do the device search in a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of any sample code, but you'll want to use the IOBluetoothDeviceInquiry class from the IOBluetooth framework. The Bluetooth Device Access Guide has a [brief section on it](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/Bluetooth/BT_Develop_BT_Apps/BT_Develop_BT_Apps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000997-CH216-BACFJHEB).

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with Gamekit Api, and btstack frame work...

but it is a big challenge .

all the best..

if u get the out put .. pls post ur experience . i am also looking that one.